# Vim tagslist plugin not detecting custom language (racket)

Tags: vim, ctags, taglist, tagbar

I've recently started using racket, and one of the first things I've done has been to try and get the vim [TagList plugin](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) to work with it. However, it doesn't work in the slightest. I can open racket files and the TagList window will be as blank as if I had opened a text file.

According to the [extending page](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/extend.html)* I have added the following to my ~/.vimrc file:

```
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = 'ctags --langdef=racket --langmap=racket:.rkt --regex-racket=/^\(def[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\?\/\\]+[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/\\\?]+)/\1/d,definition/'
let Tlist_racket_settings = 'racket;d:Definition'
```

The extra ctags stuff is also in my ~/.ctags file, but TList was spitting out errors about my setting line not being any good. I did original try to use ctags existing scheme functionality, but I had the same nothing results. To use the existing scheme functionality, i tried the following in my ~/.vimrc

```
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = 'ctags --langmap=scheme:.rkt'
let Tlist_racket_settings = 'racket;f:Functions'
```

If anyone else has any ideas on how to get it working, then I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks,

- I'd post a link to the ctags one page as well, but it wont let me (new user). A link to it can be found on the extending taglist page.

**EDIT**

**ctags from the command line**

I can use ctags from the command line. Testing with the ctags line on the TagList FAQ page I get the following:

```
 $ cat ~/.ctags
--langdef=racket
--langmap=racket:.rkt
--regex-racket=/^\(def[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\?\/\\]+[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/\\\?]+)/\1/d,definition/
--regex-racket=/^\(define\-syntax(\-rule)?[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/\\\?]+)/\2/m,macro/
--regex-racket=/^\(define?[ \t]+(([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/\\\?]+)[ \t]+\(lambda|\(([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/\\\?]+))/\2\3/f,function/
$ ctags  -f - --format=2 --excmd=pattern --fields=nks XMMSClient.rkt 
defenum XMMSClient.rkt  /^(define-syntax defenum$/;"    m   line:11
defxmmsc    XMMSClient.rkt  /^(define-syntax defxmmsc$/;"   m   line:20
libxmmsclient   XMMSClient.rkt  /^(define libxmmsclient (ffi-lib "libxmmsclient"))$/;"  d   line:5
```

Output is the same if I force the language definition with switches, or if I change the language to scheme.

**About TagBar**

I had not seen TagBar before people had suggested it. Interestingly enough, it just worked with the changes to my .ctags file. Unfortunately, I've not found a setting for showing the tags from all loaded buffers the way TagList does, so I would prefer to use TagList.

I'd post comparison images, but I don't think its going to let me, as a new member. As per romainl's suggestion, I can set the vim filetype to scheme, and it does work. This however only seems like an 80% solution, when the documentation according to the extending pages seems to suggest that what I have should work. Perhaps I should be looking at filing a bug report.

Thanks again,

Comment: Do your settings work when you use ctags directly from the command line? If not it's not a problem with TagList or Vim but with your regular expression.

Comment: Does this `--langmap=scheme:.rkt` work, when ctags is used directly?

Comment: try tagbar looks better than taglist

Comment: @locojay Indeed it does, but it does not (as far as I can see) display the tags of multiple buffers at once.

Comment: @romainl yes to both questions. I'm editing the post to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small racket snippet I lifted from the [official documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/quick/index.html) and saved as `tt.rkt`:

```
(define (checker p1 p2)
  (let ([p12 (hc-append p1 p2)]
        [p21 (hc-append p2 p1)])
    (vc-append p12 p21)))
```

Without racket-specific syntax/indent files nothing is shown whether `ft` is set to `racket` (of course) or nothing (the default). If I `:set ft=scheme`, both TagList and [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) list `checker` as "function".

From left to right: the file, TagBar, TagList.

[image: TagList and TagBar against a racket file]

From what I understand, "Racket" is a rebranding of some Scheme derivative. If it doesn't deviate too much from the norm, adding this line in your `~/.vimrc` may help:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.rkt set filetype=scheme
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'd not actually found TagBar, and interestingly enough it just worked with my .ctags file, which I added to as I tested it. Unfortunately, while it does work it doesn't display tags from multiple buffers at once (at least, I didn't see an option for it). I'd like to see if I can get the problem fixed, but it is good to know I can work around it. Thanks.

Comment: No, TagBar doesn't show tags for multiple buffers, you can still use native commands like `:tselect`, though. It's not as pretty and convenient but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same issue, though for xslt files... My solution was found by poking around in taglist.vim, whereby I added a line for

```
let s:tlist_def_xslt_settings = 'xslt;f:function:v:variable'
```

try doing a search for the s:tlist_def_ parts of the Vim code and put in something which looks sensible. There's a similar mechanism within Tagbar. I've not read the code through in detail, so I don't know why it would need this and not use the output from cta

Comment: N.B. my code line above isn't complete... just for example only.